# Cointegration between two stationary processes

Tags: stationarity, cointegration

I have two stationary time series. I would like to check for cointegration between them. Does this make sense, and can I just use Engle-Granger Test (two step) for Cointegration for this?

Comment: I come to think of it that just plain correlation or (adjusted) R^2 are the same for stationary processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it does not make sense to look for cointegration among stationary time series. Cointegration can only take place if the individual time series are integrated (thus non-stationary).

The basic idea can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration): *If two or more series are individually integrated ... but some linear combination of them has a lower order of integration, then the series are said to be cointegrated.*

Comment: already got the answer, one could use just correlation

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is absolutely true, if the series are already stationary at levels , running a cointegration does not make sense ( It requires data to be I(1) or integrated of the same order). If the data are already stationary then it makes sense to proceed with VAR.